# What are common ways of presenting features that share coordinates?

Tags: cartography, wfs, symbology, overlapping-features

When I encounter features of the same class, but with identical coordinates I lay them out in a spiral arm formation.  I chose to pick the initial radius and angle at random (can't recall my actual motive).  My question is this:

Is there a standard way (or ways) of symbolizing features, from any WFS service, which would otherwise stack on top of each other in a 2D representation? For example, how does one 'best' display a transformer on a pole and the pole itself?

Comment: what 'system'? is it GIS based?

Comment: Mapperz: A collection of features from any WFS service.

Comment: What software/code are you using to read the WFS?

Comment: It would help if you could make it clearer that you are dealing with representation of such features, not storage. E.g in the title

Comment: Mapperz: get/post to WFS (1.1.0 or 1.0.0), response -> home-grown spiral algorithm -> either openlayers 2.12 or esri jsapi 3.1

Comment: steko: Any common practices would be acceptable.  How does one 'best' display a transformer on a pole and the pole itself?

Comment: Over a year later and still no answer here. Did you find an answer anywhere? You may get more help at http://www.cartotalk.com/. Either way, it would help if you showed us an example of what you already do; i'm having a hard time imagining your "spiral" technique. Finally, transformers on a pole is highly domain-specific. Electrical distribution circuits, weather maps, geology maps, etc, all have their own conventions.